# Is it worth keeping the built-in render pipeline?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl, shading, shader-graph

I've been having trouble creating a simple shader for overlaying a png onto a background color as a material. I've done a lot of searching, and almost all solutions seem to be using a shadergraph. I tried it, and it works.. but I would have to convert the entire project to URP, and I don't know if it's worth it. Alternatavely I have managed to write a shader that does this, but it seems like a lot more work/time.

Do you usually just use URP and convert all other materials? Or is there a better way to do stuff like this with the built-in?

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

URP is the future of Unity and they try to implement it as a default. Because of that I strongly suggest at least learn how to use it. And I'm doing all my project with URP with no problem.